# The method countGreaterThan(T[], T) in the type GenericMethodsAndBoundedTypeParameters is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[], Integer)

Tags: java, generics

Update:

This question came up while I was learning Java Generics from the Oracle Java Tutorials, the codes were from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html, and this led me to the following error. I didn't know that Java already has the Comparable interface at that time. Problem was solved right after I removed my own Comparable interface.

Original post:

I am having trouble fixing the error in the following code. I am using JavaSE-16 on Eclipse 2021-09

```
public class GenericMethodsAndBoundedTypeParameters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = countGreaterThan(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (Integer)(2));
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
        int count = 0;
        for(T e : anArray) {
            if(e.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T obj);
}
```

The error message looks like this:

**The method countGreaterThan(T[], T) in the type GenericMethodsAndBoundedTypeParameters is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[], Integer)**

Comment: You seem to have declared your own `Comparable<T>` interface. ***Don't***

Answer (score 1):

Don't define your own `Comparable` interface. Also, you want `? super T`. Like,

```
public static <T extends java.lang.Comparable<? super T>> int countGreaterThan(
            T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray) {
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Works for me. I get `3` when I add `System.out.println(a);` in the provided `main`.

Comment: Hi Elliott, your solution worked. The error message was gone right after I removed my own Comparable interface.